# Why is my logistic regression model predicting 0s only? /small sample size?

Tags: python, logistic-regression

I am building a churn prediction model with logistic regression in python. My model accuracy is 0.47 and only predicts 0s. The realized y variable is actually 81 zeros and 92 ones.

The data set I have is only a few features and 220 users(records). If I set a reference time, it is even less(about 123 records for the training set and 173 for the testing set). So I think the sample size is too small to use logistic regression. But I still tried because this is just a sample test so I only got this small data set. (Theoretically there is more data)

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(x_train, y_train)

y_pred = logreg.predict(x_test)
print('Accuracy: {:.2f}'.format(logreg.score(x_test, y_test)))
```

Even if I don't test the model, meaning I use the whole data set to build the model, when I predict the future churn it still returns only 0s.
is it that my sample size is too small, or because the accuracy is less than 0.5 so it just returns one value(0 here) ? Or I did something wrong in the code?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Could be various things. Plot the data. Are the classes actually separable in predictor space? Is the training set representative of the test set?

Comment: How do you split into the train and test? Are you sure that the training set has both 0s and 1s in it?

Comment: I used a reference time A. Before A it goes to the training set. Before A+ days defining a churn, it goes to testing set. Before current time it's used to predict. Yes in the training set there are both 1 and 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several potential causes for heavily biased prediction from a logistic regression model. For the purpose of informing general audience, I will list the most common ones even though some of them don't apply to your case.

1. (**Skewed output distribution**) Your training data has biased, imbalanced label distribution. If your training contains, for example, 1 positive and 100000 negatives, the bias/intercept term in the regression will be very small. After applying the link function the predictions can be practically zero.
2. (**Sparsity**) The feature space is large and your dataset is small, leading to a sparse training data. Therefore most new incoming instances of data point aren't seen before. In the worse case, in which all features are factor, unseen factor values result in zeros because the correct one-hot column cannot be identified.
3. (**Skewed input distribution**) The feature space is small and your dataset is dense around a small region. If it turns out at that region there are more zeros, the predictions are always gonna be zero even for future instances of input. For example, my data X has two columns, gender and age. It turns out most of my data points are 30 years old male, and 80 out of 100 30-year-old males like ice-cream, in a 101 data-point dataset. The model will predict 30-year-old males like ice-cream for future input, which are usually for 30-year-old males assuming similar input distribution.

You should check the distribution of score using the `predict_proba` function, and check the distribution of input features using something like `pairplot`.

Comment: you are right!! my case is number 3. I further added some features and now it predicts well! thanks a lot for your help!